# Want to create a counter using first. and last. equivalent in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sorted pandas data frame like the following:

```
ID      Values
'AAAA'   1
'AAAA'   2
'AAAA'   3
'BBBB'   4
'CCCC'   5
'CCCC'   6
```

I have to create a new column `"ID_Index"` which will be like this

```
ID      Values  ID_Index
'AAAA'   1         1
'AAAA'   2         1
'AAAA'   3         1
'BBBB'   4         2
'CCCC'   5         3
'CCCC'   6         3
```

That means the code will check ID of row 1, it will start counting as 1. Then whenever there is a new id the counter will be +1. 
In SAS we used to do it using `first.id` and/or `last.id`. Here I found that using shift() we can create that. I tried the following code in python, but it is not working.

```
c=1
for index, row in df_pandas.iterrows():
    if (df_pandas['ID'] == df_pandas['ID'].shift()):
        df_pandas['ID_Index']=c
    else:
         df_pandas['ID_Index'] = c+1
print df_pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) if want same values:

```
df['new'] = pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0] + 1
```

Or if possible multiple groups:

```
df['new'] = df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift()).cumsum()
```

---

```
print (df)
       ID  Values  new
0  'AAAA'       1    1
1  'AAAA'       2    1
2  'AAAA'       3    1
3  'BBBB'       4    2
4  'CCCC'       5    3
5  'CCCC'       6    3
```

Difference best seen in added new row:

```
df['new1'] = pd.factorize(df['ID'])[0] + 1
df['new2'] = df['ID'].ne(df['ID'].shift()).cumsum()
print (df)
       ID  Values  new1  new2
0  'AAAA'       1     1     1
1  'AAAA'       2     1     1
2  'AAAA'       3     1     1
3  'BBBB'       4     2     2
4  'CCCC'       5     3     3
5  'CCCC'       6     3     3
6  'AAAA'       7     1     4
```

Comment: Since dataframe is already sorted (assuming sorted by `ID`), I think only the first scenario is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

what i do is that i would convert the ID column into a list, manually create ID_Index and then append it to the dataframe

```
ids=df_pandas['ID'].tolist()
counter=1
id_index=[1]    

for idx,id in enumerate(ids):
    if idx!=0:
        if ids[idx-1]!=id:
            counter+=1
        id_index.append(counter)

df_pandas['ID_Index']=id_index
```

sure this might not be the perfect way, but gets the job done

Comment: With Pandas, manual loops are not recommended. See @jezrael's solution and marked duplicate for vectorised solutions.